# Previous knowledge to derive Student's t-distribution

Tags: t-distribution, derived-distributions

I'd like to know what are the mathematical prerequisites that I would need to learn to derive the pdf of the Student's t-distribution

Comment: Does this post answer your question sufficiently? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474733/derivation-of-the-density-function-of-student-t-distribution-from-this-big-integ

Comment: It all depends where you start from. The pdf of a Student's $t$ distribution can be taken as a given. Or, as William Gosset derived it, as the pdf of the ratio of a Normal variate by a normalised Chi variate.

Comment: Hi Ferdi, the link takes me to a derivation, but I am more interested in the steps I have to take to understand that derivation. My knowledge of analysis is rather limited, for example I am not familiar with the gamma function. I would like to know what is the level of calculus (and a pathway to get there if possible) to understand the derivation